# How to get country name from country code?

Tags: magento-1.7, locale

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('custom/table')->getCollection();
```

I have one custom table and there is one field country_code.
Now I am passing this `$collection` to my javascript and using variables in that.
Now I want to display country name instead of country code.

Is there any way from which I can add country name in my collection using join query or any way else ?
so before passing to js I want country name in my collection object.

Answer (score 4):

Try this.

```
$countryModel = Mage::getModel('directory/country')->loadByCode($country_code);
$countryName = $countryModel->getName();
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to get the country name in English locale:

```
$locale = new Zend_Locale('en_US');
echo $locale->getTranslation($code, 'country', $locale);
```

Comment: To get default locale, use `Mage::app()->getLocale()->getTranslation($code, 'country');`

Answer (score 2):

you can try below code

```
$country_name=Mage::app()->getLocale()->getCountryTranslation($country_code);
echo $country_name;
```

Comment: Is it possible to get by join query ? so it can be new column in my collection object.

Comment: you have to design your table in such a way that you can easily got that value when you fetch your custom collection then you got this values

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the country name by country ID/code this way:

```
echo Mage::getModel(’directory/country’)->load($country_id)->getName();
```